# Android sqlite insert is not inserting

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, insert

i have this little gps locaton inserting code but thats not insert into the database:

```
db.setVersion(1);
db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
db.setLockingEnabled(true);

final String gps = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GPS_Values ("
                + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Latitude float(10, 6), Longitude float(10, 6), cur_timestamp TIMESTAMP);";
db.execSQL(gps);
```

and the inserting lines:

```
// GPS
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();

        ContentValues gps_values = new ContentValues();

        gps_values.put("Latitude", loc.getLatitude());
        gps_values.put("Longitutde", loc.getLongitude());


        try {
            db.beginTransaction();
            db.insert("GPS_Values", null, gps_values);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }

        String Text = "My current location is: " + "Latitude = "
                + loc.getLatitude() + "\nLongitude = " + loc.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

}// gps vége
```

when tring to get location everithing works fine but the inserting.

i have similar code with tha accelerator and that works fine.

pls help me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There a typo in the column you're inserting to:

```
    gps_values.put("Longitutde", loc.getLongitude());
```

Should be

```
    gps_values.put("Longitude", loc.getLongitude());
```

The `insert()` call returns -1 if an error occurred, but you aren't checking the return value. It's generally easier to use `insertOrThrow` instead, which throws an exception on error.

Comment: and that's because nothing inserting?

Comment: Yes, if you try to insert to a non-existent column it will generate an error.

Comment: ok...now it's working :) THX!!! but it's just with i don't know how to call it, so here's an example: 41.2211 <- only 4 after the 41.:)

Answer (score 15):

Try using `insertOrThrow` instead, - it will throw an exception if your db constraints don't allow a specific insertion, then you will be able to figure out.

Comment: saved my day! insertOrThrow throws an error and i know exactly what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

You try to insert in "Longitutde" but you've create "Longitude" field